# Colocando width dinamico em um Container

Tags: dart, flutter

Olá! Eu estou querendo usar esse controle para substituir as Dropdown, mas percebi que o comando width dele 'não funciona', talvez pelo contexto externo a ele, não entendi direito.
Pois eu quero na verdade tornar dinamico com valor em double que já tenho preparado, mas mesmo colocando na valor fixo ali 200.0 não obecede:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Flutter:

```
SizedBox(
              height: 34.0,
              child: GridView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.5),
                children: todostimes.times.map((s) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _timeSelecionado = s;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: s == _timeSelecionado
                                      ? Colors.deepPurple
                                      : Colors.grey[400],
                                  width: 2.0)
                          ),
                          width: 200.0, //valor fixo
                          //convertDouble(s['TimeNome'].toString()) ,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: Text(s['TimeNome'],
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ));
                }).toList(),
              ),
            )
```

GitHub (completo): https://github.com/danielgmrs/flutter_estudos/blob/master/disparar.dart

Comment: Forneça um código completo executável para que possamos testar/executar o seu problema. Facilita a análise.

Comment: Código completo: https://github.com/danielgmrs/flutter_estudos/blob/master/disparar.dart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido meu problema, apenas troquei o GRIDVIEW por LISTVIEW !

Answer (score -1):

Fala cara!

nos Width e Height tente usar:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

se for usar por porcentagem:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5 pra 50%

Comment: Valeu Alex! Mas infelizmente nao mudou... fiz debug e o width deste comando ai está com mais de 400.0 e não surtiu efeito nenhum